# How to create a new column in python under multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-loc

I would like to create a new column under the following condition:

So basically I have two column `Majoy car` and `Major housetype`.  I would let all the `'nocar'` within `Majoy car` AND `'Rented'` within `Major housetype` to merge to a new column.

My DataFrame is `imd_car_house`

I have tried: `imd_car_house.loc[(cond1) | (cond2), :]` but this is not working.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge to a new column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest it is unclear if you are using pandas but if you are, and your columns are 'Majoy car' and 'Major housetype' then the following should work if you want all the rows in your dataframe conforming to your requirements.

```
imd_car_house[(imd_car_house['Majoy car']=='nocar')&(imd_car_house['Major housetype']=='Rented)]
```